# How can I get the .data3d.buffer from my uploaded 3d model through storage API

Tags: archilogic, 3d.io

I can upload my 3d model through storage api. But I can not get the .data3d.buffer from storage api. I found the .data3d.buffer is necessary for aframe to load the 3d model. How can I get the .data3d.buffer through storage api??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the storage key, you can directly download the model from `storage.3d.io`.

Example:

```
io3d.storage.put(myFile).then(function (storageKey) {
  console.log('the data3d.buffer is now at', 'https://storage.3d.io' + storageKey)
})
```

Note that the file will have a `.gz.data3d.buffer` as the browser is going to decompress the packed asset when downloading. You may have to remove the `.gz` to be able to use the file directly.

The Storage API can be used directly, but will automatically parse the binary file into JSON for you.

To use the model in A-Frame you would only need the storage key anyway (in the browser):

```
io3d.storage.put(myFile).then(function (storageKey) {
  var model = document.createElement('a-entity')
  model.setAttribute('io3d-data3d', 'key: ' + storageKey)
  document.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(model)
})
```